# Suggestion for synonyms

Tags: feature-request, status-completed, synonym-request

I saw [this question on Stackoverflow](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/14164810/windows-authentication-for-a-single-database-call-in-a-web-application) and it would seem appropriate to somehow *consolidate* the two tags, `impersonate` and `impersonation`.

Thanks!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Agreed, this is a good candidate for consolidation.  [impersonate](/questions/tagged/impersonate) had no tag wiki, and all the questions it appeared on seemed to be about applications impersonating a user in a security context (the same as [impersonation](/questions/tagged/impersonation)), so I went ahead and performed the merge.